# Extract time from date time and find difference between 2 times

Tags: powershell

I am trying to convert EPOC time to date time and need to extract the time only from that

I am doing below

```
 $min = $Time_Start | measure -Minimum
 $max = $Time_End | measure -Maximum
 [datetime]$oUNIXDatemin=(Get-Date 01.01.1970)+([System.TimeSpan]::fromseconds($min.Minimum))
 $oUNIXDatemin_1 = $oUNIXDatemin.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
 [datetime]$oUNIXDatemax=(Get-Date 01.01.1970)+([System.TimeSpan]::fromseconds($max.Maximum))
 $oUNIXDatemax_1 = $oUNIXDatemax.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
```

Problem is while converting I am getting **$oUNIXDatemin_1** and **$oUNIXDatemax_1** value like

```
$oUNIXDatemin_1

12 October 2021 07:46:46

$oUNIXDatemax_1

12 October 2021 21:16:04
```

My EPOC values are

```
$min.Minimum
1634024806

$max.Maximum
1634073364
```

Please let me know what is wrong here. Need to find the difference in **HH:mm:ss** format.

Comment: where do `$Time_Start` & `$Time_End` come from? what is in them?

Comment: set of EPOC time in both. from that I am fetching the minimum and maximum values

Comment: ah! thank you ... but next time, please define all your info in the Question so that folks like me won't waste your time asking unneeded question ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell, you'd usually use a format string. Subtracting two PowerShell datetimes returns a value of type Timespan, which is well-behaved over a span of more than 24 hours.

```
([datetime]"12 October 2021 21:16:04" - [datetime]"12 October 2021 07:46:46") -f "HH:mm:ss"
13:29:18
```

Be careful here. Both intervals (durations) and time (of day) have the same format, but different meanings. For example, it makes sense to multiply the interval "01:00:00" (1 hour) by 3 to get three hours; it doesn't make sense to multiply the time "01:00:00" (1 o'clock AM) by 3.

I'm sure the overall calculation can be simplified, but it's too early for me.

Comment: Mike, Can you please tell me the first part. how to extract the time from the datetime. like only 21:16:04 from "12 October 2021 21:16:04"

Comment: @EmptyCoder - simply subtract the two DateTime objects to get the difference ... and then use the format that you want to _display_ the value in.

Comment: @EmptyCoder: Values like "12 October 2021 21:16:04" are strings. Strings support the `-split` operator. Split the datetime string on a space, and take the last element (*not* the 4th element) of the resulting array: `("12 October 2021 21:16:04" -split " ")[-1]`. Be advised that careful programmers don't do date arithmetic on only the times.